# Add a subplot within a figure using a for loop and python/matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I dont think you need all the code to help me with this, this was working 3 months ago but now the subplots are not getting added to the same figure. i.e. I want one figure 2 by 2 populated with a different line chart for each of the 4 countries in my table. what i currently get is one figure with 4 empty charts and 4 subsequent individual charts. why is this not getting adding to the same chart correctly now?

I have upgraded python and pandas since that time and anaconda(spyder) which I use. I am currently using the following versions:

Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)
Matplotlib 1.3.1
Pandas 0.15.2

```
for i, group in df.groupby('Country'):
   chrt += 1 
   fig1.add_subplot(2,2, chrt)
   #fig1.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
   group.plot(x='Month', y='Value (USD)',title= str(i))
```

Comment: What kind of object is group?  (For the group.plot)  I am not a python expert, but usually what I do when plotting is something more like ax=fig1.add_subplot(...), then ax.plot( ... something involving group ... )

Comment: Thanks TravisJ, I guess I was just struggling to get the ( ... something involving group ... ) in when i was using the ax=fig1....method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things come to mind. Make sure `fig1` and `chrt` are well initialized. Then, you can specify which axis it plots on with the `ax` keyword.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1 = plt.figure()
chrt = 0
for i, group in df.groupby('Country'):
    chrt += 1 
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(2,2, chrt)
    group.plot(x='Month', y='Value (USD)',title=str(i), ax=ax)
```

Comment: thanks @Julien Spronck the ax=ax was the trick I hadnt tried, still dont understand it all but it works.