# How to add gridlines between each GridSpec subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-gridspec

I have a `matplotlib` `gridspec` plot as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=[8,8])
spec2 = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=2, figure=fig2)
f2_ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(spec2[0, 0])
f2_ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(spec2[0, 1])
f2_ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(spec2[1, 0])
f2_ax4 = fig2.add_subplot(spec2[1, 1])
```

[image]

I want to add gridlines for the above plot. I'm not able to do that with `hlines` as `gridpec` attribute has no object `hlines`.

Is it possible to add **gridlines** for `gridspec` object in **matplotlib** as below:

[image]

Comment: https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/horizontal-and-vertical-lines-between-subplots/13540 this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, but the following solution takes into account decorations on the axes (note how the grid goes below the xlabel).  You could probably simplify if you know exactly where your axes are going to be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, constrained_layout=True)

axs[0, 0].set_xlabel('Boo')
fig.draw_without_rendering()

trans = fig.transFigure

# line after the first column:
right = 0
for a in axs[:, 0]:
    bb = trans.inverted().transform_bbox(a.get_tightbbox(renderer=fig.canvas.get_renderer()))
    right = max(right, bb.x1)
right = right + 0.01
fig.add_artist(mpl.lines.Line2D([right, right], [0, 1], linestyle='--'))

# line after first row
bottom = 1
for a in axs[0, :]:
    bb = trans.inverted().transform_bbox(a.get_tightbbox(renderer=fig.canvas.get_renderer()))
    bottom = min(bottom, bb.y0)
bottom = bottom - 0.01
fig.add_artist(mpl.lines.Line2D([0, 1], [bottom, bottom], linestyle='--'), )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using  `spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=2, figure=fig)` instead of `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, constrained_layout=True)`. How to get the `axs` in gridspec?

Comment: use `f2_ax1` etc instead of `axs[..,..]`.

Comment: But using gridspec and a bunch of `add_subplot` calls is not very idiomatic...

Comment: Actually, in my case, I'm adding plot/figure in for loop to single plot using `gridspec`

Comment: Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70574478/14045537)

Comment: Error `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'draw_without_rendering'`

Comment: You have an older version of Matplotlib.  You can try `fig.canvas.draw()`.  As for your loop, that is more easily done as I have suggested above - instead of passing `fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])` to your plotting routine, pass `axs[0, 0]`.

Comment: or if you are copying that other code exactly pass `axs.flat[i]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240757/discussion-between-pluviophile-and-jody-klymak).